# how to add new row to UItableview with smooth scrolling

Tags: iphone

i am adding some images and messages getting from .net web server.

i am refreshing the data for every 3 sec.

After 3 sec i am getting new messages.I need to add these messages and images at the top of the UITableview.

like messages adding in twitter,[google realtime](http://www.google.co.in/search?tbs=mbl:1&hl=en&source=hp&q=twitter&btnG=Search).

for that some where i found  insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation: rather then reloading the table view.

but i did n't understand how can i use this insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation: method.

if it is correct can any one please post some code other wise please suggest better way for this.

thank u in advance.

Comment: Use insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation from UITableView

Answer (score 1):

You simply create an array with the index paths of the new rows you want to insert (`+[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:inSection:]`) and then pass that array to `insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:`.

The table view will then call the appropriate data source methods (`tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` etc.) to ask your data source for the data of the new rows. So the moment you call `insertRowsAtIndexPaths:...`, your data source must already contain the data for the new rows. And that's it.

Answer (score 1):

> insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:
> Inserts rows in the receiver at the
> locations identified by an array of
> index paths, with an option to animate
> the insertion.
>
> - (void)insertRowsAtIndexPaths:(NSArray
>   *)indexPaths withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimation)animation
>   Parameters indexPaths An array of
>   NSIndexPath objects each representing
>   a row index and section index that
>   together identify a row in the table
>   view. animation A constant that either
>   specifies the kind of animation to
>   perform when inserting the cell or
>   requests no animation. See “Table Cell
>   Insertion and Deletion Animation” for
>   descriptions of the constants.
>   Discussion UITableView calls the
>   relevant delegate and data source
>   methods immediately afterwards to get
>   the cells and other content for
>   visible cells.
>
> Note the behavior of this method when
> it is called in an animation block
> defined by the beginUpdates and
> endUpdates methods. UITableView defers
> any insertions of rows or sections
> until after it has handled the
> deletions of rows or sections. This
> happens regardless of ordering of the
> insertion and deletion method calls.
> This is unlike inserting or removing
> an item in a mutable array, where the
> operation can affect the array index
> used for the successive insertion or
> removal operation. For more on this
> subject, see “Batch Insertion and
> Deletion of Rows and Sections” in
> Table View Programming Guide for iOS.
>
> Availability Available in iOS 2.0 and
> later.

From [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:)

First you need to generate the indexPaths array. To generate them you can use

```
+ (NSIndexPath *)indexPathForRow:(NSUInteger)row inSection:(NSUInteger)section;
```

Docs [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/NSIndexPath_UIKitAdditions/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSIndexPath/indexPathForRow:inSection:)

And you must update your dataSource array and the `numberOfRowsInSection` must return the correct value [old value + numberOfAddedRows];